# SASS/CSS: Media Queries prone to breaking

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm having some problems writing the media queries to make my site responsive. To keep everything tidy I have the mobile stylesheet written in a separate file (mobile.css.scss) like so:

```
@media (min-width: 340px) and (max-width: 767px){

    /* hide desktop only code and display mobile elements */

    .menu{display: none;}
    .banner-desktop{display: none;}
    .banner-mobile{
        display: block !important;
        img{width: 99%;}
    }

    /* general styling */

    .page-body{
        width: 99% !important;
    }
}
```

and my desktop styling is in application.css.scss:

```
body{

    /* Hide mobile only stuff */
    .banner-mobile{display:none;}

    /* General Styling */

    .page-body{
        width: 1167px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;     
    }
}
```

The problem is that some of the mobile styling is not being read unless I have !important next to it as shown above. I'm new to and not yet 100% comfortable with css/sass but I'm reasonably certain that this sort of approach is not the way to go about things. I could end up with !important down the entire stylesheet!

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong so any help at all would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `!important` should always be your last resort, they almost always cause more specifity problems than they solve.  Media queries do not alter the specificity of the selectors.  If the specificity of the selector is equal, then last matching selector wins.

When you have this:

```
@media (min-width: 30em) {
    .foo {
        color: red;
    }
}

.foo {
    color: blue;
}
```

For devices that are larger than 30em wide, it is the same as this:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}

.foo {
    color: blue;
}
```

So, what you're actually looking for is something like this:

```
// styles that apply to *all* devices go here (see: mobile first methodology)
// repeatedly setting/unsetting styles is inefficient and should be
// avoided whenever it is reasonable to do so

@media (max-width: 767px) { // narrow viewport only
    .menu, .banner-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) { // bigger than the narrow viewport
    .banner-mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

There is zero benefit to having individual CSS files because *all* devices download them, even if they do not currently match against the media queries.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should have ALL my styling in one stylesheet? Put stuff that applies to everything first then  mobile only then larger devices? This actually sounds like it makes a lot of sense but putting everything in one stylesheet has the potential to be very, very messy. Using scaffolding with rails generates a stylesheet for each controller so I alway assumed that was to help keep styling neat and organised. Am I mistaken in that assumption?

Comment: There's no benefit to doing that from the perspective of the client.  What the final CSS file looks like is irrelevant (provided it is reasonably optimized):  all that matters is that your Sass code is organized in a way that makes sense for you.  Having individual style sheets that are specific to a page/group of pages *might* be a reasonable optimization, but it is rarely necessary.  There might be other reasons to do so, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Okay, well I'll do a bit of re-organisation later before I get too far into the styling to make such a task inadvisable. Thanks for the input @cimmanon, I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because re-organizing my media queries as per your suggestion meant that there was no longer a need for !important. Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue

--

**!important**

We've done [responsive interface work before](https://github.com/richpeck/accountancy_demo/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/layout/responsive.css.scss), and found you'll have to use `!important` to get things to work for many of the elements.

I think the problem is the `@media` query basically just appends a new set of styles to your elements (kind of like how inline styles work)

This means if you want to override specific values (from what I remember, `width` was one of these), you'll need to use `!important`

--

Bottom line is I don't think you're doing anything "wrong" by calling `!important` - you just need to be able to keep the code structured & clean

Comment: Really? Well that's a relief to know. I thought for sure I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using `!important` is considered harmful, and you should never use it unless you absolutely have to.  This is not one of those cases.